# Bluez4 get device name during agent pair

Tags: python, bluetooth, bluez

I am implementing a custom Bluetooth pairing agent in Python using Bluez via DBUS.  The agent needs to return one of a number of fixed PIN codes (legacy PINs, not simple pair mode requests) depending on which type of device is trying to pair.  The devices are Bluetooth enabled medical monitors (blood pressure, scales etc) of which I have no control.

Originally, I was looking at the first bit of the devices Mac address and returning a PIN based on the manufacture prefix.  This was working well.  But the device I am now trying to add support for uses the same prefix (I assume it has the same BT chip) but a different PIN as one of the other devices I need to support.  The only thing unique about the devices are their names which are always constant (such as "AND 1234" or "IEM 5678") so I tried to change by agent to look at the first bit of the name instead

```
knownPins = {
    "aandd": "12345",
    "iem ": "5678",
    "default": "98689"
}

@dbus.service.method("org.bluez.Agent", in_signature="o", out_signature="s")
def RequestPinCode(self, device):
    pprint("RequestPinCode ({})", device)   
    dbdevice = dbus.Interface(bus.get_object("org.bluez", device),
        "org.bluez.Device")

    bits = device.split('/')
    mac = bits[-1].replace("dev_","").replace("_",":").lower()      
    props = dbdevice.GetProperties()
    if not props["Name"]:
        raise Rejected()
    try:
        for name, pin in knownPins.items():
            if props["Name"].startswith(name):
                return pin

        return knownPins["default"]
    except:
        raise Rejected()
```

But, in most cases `props["Name"]` is simply empty - i assume this is because the pair request is being initiated by the remote party and since I have not done a discover, I dont know its name.

So my question is, how can I force a inquiry at this point in the process so I can get the device name?  I have tried

```
adapter.CreateDevice(mac)
```

Which gives `org.bluez.Error.AlreadyExists`

I have tried

```
adapter.RemoveDevice(device)
adapter.CreateDevice(mac)
```

Which gives `org.bluez.Error.DoesNotExist: Device creation in progress`

I assume in both instances this is because Bluez is in the middle of trying to create the device

Thanks